# Automatic conversion of standard function into asynchronous function in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-decorators

In most of the asynchronous coroutines I write, I only need to replace the function definition `def func()` -> `async def func()` and the sleep `time.sleep(s)` -> `await asyncio.sleep(s)`.

**Is it possible to convert a standard python function into an async function where all the `time.sleep(s)` is converted to `await asyncio.sleep(s)`?**

### Example

**Performance during task**
Measure performance during a task

```
import asyncio
import random

async def performance_during_task(task):
    stop_event = asyncio.Event()

    target_task = asyncio.create_task(task(stop_event))
    perf_task = asyncio.create_task(measure_performance(stop_event))

    await target_task
    await perf_task

async def measure_performance(event):
    while not event.is_set():
        print('Performance: ', random.random())
        await asyncio.sleep(.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(
        performance_during_task(task)
    )
```

**Task**
The task has to be defined with `async def` and `await asyncio.sleep(s)`

```
async def task(event):
    for i in range(10):
        print('Step: ', i)
        await asyncio.sleep(.2)
    
    event.set()
```

into ->

**Easy task definition**
To have others not worrying about async etc. I want them to be able to define a task normally (e.g. with a decorator?)

```
@as_async
def easy_task(event):
    for i in range(10):
        print('Step: ', i)
        time.sleep(.2)
    
    event.set()
```

So that it can be used as an async function with e.g. `performance_during_task()`

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/phizaz/20c36c6734878c6ec053245a477572ec) may be interesting to explore

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution similar to the interesting GitHub example mentioned in the comments and a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241221/how-can-i-wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-an-async-coroutine).

We can write a **decorator** like

```
from functools import wraps, partial


def to_async(func):
    @wraps(func)  # Makes sure that function is returned for e.g. func.__name__ etc.
    async def run(*args, loop=None, executor=None, **kwargs):
        if loop is None:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop(). # Make event loop of nothing exists
        pfunc = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)  # Return function with variables (event) filled in
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, pfunc).
    return run
```

Such that **easy task** becomes

```
@to_async
def easy_task(event):
    for i in range(10):
        print('Step: ', i)
        time.sleep(.2)
    
    event.set()
```

Where *wraps* makes sure we can call attributes of the original function ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308999/what-does-functools-wraps-do)).

And *partial* fills in the variables as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does/15331841).