# timeout in asynchronous function in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I will give an example of a simple asynchronous code

```py
import asyncio
import time


async def do_asynchronous(function, items, chunk_size=10, task_timeout=None):
    items_slices = [items[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(items), chunk_size)]
    result = list()
    for row in items_slices:
        tasks = [asyncio.wait_for(function(i), timeout=task_timeout) for i in row]
        result += await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    return result


async def foo(item):
    if item != 10:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return item
    else:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        return 'oops'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    items = list(range(20))
    start = time.time()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(do_asynchronous(foo, items, chunk_size=5, task_timeout=1.2))
    print(f'{time.time() - start}')
    print(result)
```

we get the following result:

```
time took: 4.2078893184661865
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, TimeoutError(), 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

but if you change foo function a bit like this:

```py
async def foo(item):
    if item!=10:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return item
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        return 'oops'
```

the result of executing the code will be as follows

```
time took: 8.01030683517456
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'oops', TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), TimeoutError(), 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

In the first case, the code worked as I expected. When the timeout is exceeded in one of the tasks, a TimeoutError is raised, and the other tasks complete correctly. But in the second case, for some reason, the code waits for 5 seconds and all 5 tasks that were sent to gather end with TimeoutError.
Why is this happening and how to achieve the first result in the second case? That is, how can I cancel only one blocking task by timeout?

Comment: You are calling a synchronous function which consumes the time. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241221/how-can-i-wrap-a-synchronous-function-in-an-async-coroutine to see how to run it asynchronously.